# Randomly getting D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 0) in lollipop

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-5.0-lollipop, android-volley, okhttp

I am facing this issue where our app crashes randomly through the checkout process, this crash occurs only on lollipop, other version it works fine. There is no information in the log cat except Fatal Signal. Also this issue cannot be reproduced on emulator, it only occurs on the device running lollipop.

I refactored the network calls and now I am getting OpenGL Renderer: Flushing caches issue. This happens after making some volley requests.

```
    06-22 18:48:29.876  24145-24216/com.pangea.android.debug D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 0)
    06-22 18:48:29.877  24145-24157/com.pangea.android.debug A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x12c7c000 in tid 24157 (FinalizerDaemon)
```

For network stack I am using Volley and OkHttp

Volley request is simple get request.

Are there any suggestions on how to get more information on the crash?

Here is sample codes to create connection:

```
    protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = new OkUrlFactory(mClient).open(url);
        return connection;
    }

    private HttpURLConnection openConnection(URL url, Request<?> request)    throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection = createConnection(url);

    int timeoutMs = request.getTimeoutMs();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(timeoutMs);
    connection.setReadTimeout(timeoutMs);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setDoInput(true);

    // use caller-provided custom SslSocketFactory, if any, for HTTPS
    if ("https".equals(url.getProtocol()) && mSslSocketFactory != null) {
        ((HttpsURLConnection) connection).setSSLSocketFactory(mSslSocketFactory);
    }

    return connection;
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
    06-18 18:08:39.427      915-915/? D/WIFI_ICON﹕ WifiActivity: 3
    06-18 18:08:39.427      915-915/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ dumpIcon[(gone) stat_sys_5signal_5|null stat_sys_wifi_signal_inandout_4 (gone) F]
    06-18 18:08:39.627    1006-1016/com.pangea.android.debug W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 33.602ms
    06-18 18:08:39.657    1006-1021/com.pangea.android.debug I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 67796(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 3(150KB) LOS objects, 40% free, 12MB/21MB, paused 5.066ms total 149.122ms
    06-18 18:08:39.667    1006-1018/com.pangea.android.debug A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x656d616c in tid 1018 (FinalizerDaemon)
    06-18 18:08:39.667    1006-1018/com.pangea.android.debug W/libc﹕ Security Level: (1), Debug inforamtion is controlled by the DUMPABLE flag.
    06-18 18:08:39.667  11804-11804/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    06-18 18:08:39.667  11804-11804/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'htc/htc_asia_tw/dlxpul:5.0.2/LRX22G/507296.103:user/release-keys'
    06-18 18:08:39.667  11804-11804/? I/DEBUG﹕ Revision: '2'
    06-18 18:08:39.667  11804-11804/? I/DEBUG﹕ ABI: 'arm'
    06-18 18:08:39.667  11804-11804/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 1006, tid: 1018, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> com.pangea.android.debug <<<
    06-18 18:08:39.667  11804-11804/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x656d616c
    06-18 18:08:39.687  11804-11804/? I/DEBUG﹕ r0 b7982668  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
    06-18 18:08:39.687  11804-11804/? I/DEBUG﹕ r4 b7982668  r5 656d616e  r6 12c638a0  r7 ffffffff
    06-18 18:08:39.687  11804-11804/? I/DEBUG﹕ r8 70c07e38  r9 b738d940  sl 12c9a1f0  fp 12c638a0
    06-18 18:08:39.687  11804-11804/? I/DEBUG﹕ ip b6ea10ec  sp b455aa78  lr b6bcf17f  pc 656d616c  cpsr 60070010
    06-18 18:08:39.687  11804-11804/? I/DEBUG﹕ backtrace:
    06-18 18:08:39.687  11804-11804/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00 pc 656d616c  <unknown>
    06-18 18:08:39.687  11804-11804/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01 pc 0002017d  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::freeDataNoInit()+22)
    06-18 18:08:39.687  11804-11804/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02 pc 000201a3  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::~Parcel()+4)
    06-18 18:08:39.687  11804-11804/? I/DEBUG﹕ #03 pc 00080683  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
    06-18 18:08:39.687  11804-11804/? I/DEBUG﹕ #04 pc 000173c9  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
    06-18 18:08:40.158      915-915/? I/RemoteViews﹕ reapply : com.tmobile.pr.mytmobile 1 15
    06-18 18:08:40.428      653-653/? E/WifiTrafficPoller﹕ TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 244 num clients 13
    06-18 18:08:40.428      653-653/? E/WifiTrafficPoller﹕ packet count Tx=111024 Rx=151852
    06-18 18:08:40.468    3087-3187/? W/SQLiteCursor﹕ Close cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@19398b3 on null twice or more
    06-18 18:08:40.468    3087-3187/? W/SQLiteCursor﹕ Close cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@31d0be70 on null twice or more
    06-18 18:08:40.758      271-828/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB﹕ Received nl msg, recvmsg returned 64
    06-18 18:08:40.758      271-828/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB﹕ Received command: ID=NETMGR_KIF_MSG_CMD, link=8
    06-18 18:08:40.758      271-828/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB﹕ Received nl msg, recvmsg returned 64
    06-18 18:08:40.758      271-828/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB﹕ Received command: ID=NETMGR_KIF_MSG_CMD, link=8
    06-18 18:08:40.758      271-679/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB﹕ Process command: ID=NETMGR_KIF_MSG_CMD, link=8, state=1
    06-18 18:08:40.758      271-679/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB﹕ Processing RTM_NEWADDR
    06-18 18:08:40.758      271-679/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB﹕ Metainfo:  Family=10 PrefixLen=64 Scope=0x0 Index=13 Flags=[0x0]
    06-18 18:08:40.758      271-679/? I/QC-NETMGR-LIB﹕ Attribute: PrefixIPv6 addr [2601:0240:d100:9900:867a:88ff:fe77:631c]
    06-18 18:08:40.758      271-679/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB﹕ Attribute: Address Cache Info - prefered=7200 valid=7200 cstamp=0x3924d8 tstamp=0x50cfc1
    06-18 18:08:40.758      271-679/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB﹕ Rcvd Netlink msg type [20]
    06-18 18:08:40.758      271-679/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB﹕ unrecognized ifindex 13
    06-18 18:08:40.758      271-679/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB﹕ Process command: ID=NETMGR_KIF_MSG_CMD, link=8, state=1
    06-18 18:08:40.758      271-679/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB﹕ Processing RTM_NEWADDR
    06-18 18:08:40.758      271-679/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB﹕ Metainfo:  Family=10 PrefixLen=64 Scope=0x0 Index=13 Flags=[0x1]TEMPORARY
    06-18 18:08:40.758      271-679/? I/QC-NETMGR-LIB﹕ Attribute: PrefixIPv6 addr [2601:0240:d100:9900:fdad:b042:7f6c:e7cc]
    06-18 18:08:40.758      271-679/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB﹕ Attribute: Address Cache Info - prefered=7200 valid=7200 cstamp=0x3924d8 tstamp=0x50cfc1
    06-18 18:08:40.758      271-679/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB﹕ Rcvd Netlink msg type [20]
    06-18 18:08:40.758      271-679/? E/QC-NETMGR-LIB﹕ unrecognized ifindex 13
    06-18 18:08:40.758      653-723/? D/libc﹕ [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 38(0x323630313a3234),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
    06-18 18:08:40.758      653-723/? D/libc﹕ [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
    06-18 18:08:40.758      653-723/? D/libc﹕ [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 38(0x323630313a3234),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
    06-18 18:08:40.758      653-723/? D/libc﹕ [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
    06-18 18:08:40.758      653-723/? D/libc﹕ [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 16(0x323030313a3535),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
    06-18 18:08:40.758      653-723/? D/libc﹕ [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
    06-18 18:08:40.758      653-723/? D/libc﹕ [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 16(0x323030313a3535),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
    06-18 18:08:40.758      653-723/? D/libc﹕ [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
    06-18 18:08:40.828     653-3231/? E/ActivityManager﹕ App crashed! Process: com.pangea.android.debug
    06-18 18:08:40.828      653-722/? I/BootReceiver﹕ Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_03 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
    06-18 18:08:40.828     653-2659/? E/SharedPreferencesImpl﹕ Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file shared_prefs/log_files.xml
    06-18 18:08:40.828     653-3231/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.pangea.android.debug/com.pangea.android.ui.activities.MainActivity
    06-18 18:08:40.878     653-3231/? D/PMS﹕ acquireWL(382218fc): PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK  ActivityManager-Launch 0x1 653 1000 null
    06-18 18:08:40.898     653-1400/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Recipient 1006
    06-18 18:08:40.898     653-1098/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{1b796396 u0 com.pangea.android.debug/com.pangea.android.ui.activities.MainActivity}
    06-18 18:08:40.908      653-724/? D/StatusBarManagerService﹕ setSystemUiVisibility(0x0)
```

Comment: Do you have some code to show us? is gonna be hard to guess what you are doing and where just with the stack. My first guess would be a lifecycle problem but that's just a guess.

Comment: Kalem, I added some code from HttpStack. Any suggestion on how I can narrow down the issue more. Thanks.

Comment: it'd be good if you put all inside an AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

Seems that system fails instantiate `Parcel` reference when it comes from/in background or in your case Fragment states.

Trace says that it fails to release memory before it creates new instance.

```
  06-18 18:08:39.687  11804-11804/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00 pc 656d616c  <unknown>
    06-18 18:08:39.687  11804-11804/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01 pc 0002017d  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::freeDataNoInit()+22)
    06-18 18:08:39.687  11804-11804/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02 pc 000201a3  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::~Parcel()+4)
    06-18 18:08:39.687  11804-11804/? I/DEBUG﹕ #03 pc 00080683  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
    06-18 18:08:39.687  11804-11804/? I/DEBUG﹕ #04 pc 000173c9  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
```

Check line [293](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/jb-dev/libs/binder/Parcel.cpp) and function `freeDataNoInit()`